# ng4: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template, angular-material-stepper

i am using angular material stepper  and the functionality is working as expected and getting below error:

[image]

[Live Demo:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2woxg)

Comment: Move initializing FormGroups from ngOnInit to constructor and the error should go away https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqfnya?file=app/step-one.component.ts

Comment: you can get explanation of @yurzui's comment here https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Answer (score 0):

when you change the value at the beginning on the ngAfterInit method some times need a delay.

```
    setTimeout(() => {
          //Code Here
      x=Object //new value
        }, 0);
    setTimeout(() => {
          //Code Here
        });
```

this work for me

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to avoid the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in general is to use the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your components:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: '/path/to/my-component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

Components using the Push ChangeDetectionStrategy only rerender the DOM if the data displayed has changed instead of rerendering on every Angular change detection cycle. Therefore, this spares a lot of ressources on the client side.

You might want to consider the "downside" that object references passed via `@Input()` would not trigger this component's change detection and thus the need to eventually trigger it manually with a `ChangeDetectorRef`, but at the end this approach will lead to cleaner component property/data stream management.